# How can I remove the parenthesis and all of the text inside of it using c#?

Tags: c#, regex

here is the example:

```
(abad_string.cpp To abad_string.cpp :  0.00%
Data Type: 0.00%
Control Structure: 0.00%
0 VARIABLES are the same

abad_string.cpp To Alarcon_string.cpp :  81.03%
Data Type: 100.00%
Control Structure: 0.00%
2 VARIABLES are the same

)

Alarcon_string.cpp To abad_string.cpp :  81.03%
Data Type: 100.00%
Control Structure: 0.00%
2 VARIABLES are the same

Alarcon_string.cpp To Alarcon_string.cpp :  0.00%
Data Type: 0.00%
Control Structure: 0.00%
0 VARIABLES are the same

)
```

i want to remove all the text inside of the parenthesis...
i want the result like this..

```
Alarcon_string.cpp To abad_string.cpp :  81.03%
Data Type: 100.00%
Control Structure: 0.00%
2 VARIABLES are the same

Alarcon_string.cpp To Alarcon_string.cpp :  0.00%
Data Type: 0.00%
Control Structure: 0.00%
0 VARIABLES are the same

)
```

i try this code but all of the text is remove :(

```
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(
    richTextBox1.Text, "((.*?)\n)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

pls help. TIA!

Comment: This is rather a regular expression question. I would suggest to add the tag for REGEX.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following solution. You usually have to delimit special characters like parenthesis in order to use them in your RegEx expression.

```
(\(.*?\))*
```

Also, there are two solutions to this problem depending on what kind of text you put into the RexEg machine. If you are using new lines in your text, you should use `@"(\([\S\s]*?\))*"`. The [\S\s] means anything that is or is not a space. In other words, literally any ASCII character. If you do not use new lines, you should simply use `@"(\(.*?\))*"`.

---

> Using New Lines

```
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, @"(\([\S\s]*?\))*", "");
```

> Not Using New Lines

```
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, @"(\(.*?\))*", "");
```

Comment: i try this code. but it doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: I updated the post. It should work now. I didn't test it earlier and assumed it would work.